# How to use addFormatters in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: converters, formatter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc // <mvc:annotation-driven />
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new EmailConverter());
    }
}
```

I add a `Converter` in `FormatterRegistry`,but I don't know how to use it,  can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

When we user `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in an `@Configuration` class,
it's using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` as default-spring-mvc config file.

There is configuration in it:

```
@Bean
public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
    FormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
    addFormatters(conversionService);
    return conversionService;
}
```

So when we override `addFormatters` and add a custom converter like `EmailConverter`, we can use like this:

```
@Inject
private ConversionService mvcConversionService; 

@RequestMapping(value = "/convert-email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void convertEmail(String email) {
    Email coEmail = mvcConversionService.convert(email, Email.class);
    System.out.println(coEmail);
}
```